# How to know which version of QuickBooks (Pro/Premier/Enterprise) the user is using with IPP v2?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Edit:  I'm not looking for the software.  I want to be able to figure out which version of the software the user is using.  It doesn't look like the Company object holds this information from what I see here:    https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Company

I know we can get the flavour and the version (year), but I didn't see a way to get the edition.  The reason we want this is because Pro version doesn't have the Sales Order feature, and our app should know this.

Comment: You can purchase a Not For Resale copy of QuickBooks that includes Premier or Enterprise here: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb/0030_NFR_Software

Comment: @JarredKeneally I edited my question, it was ambiguous I see now.

Comment: QBVersion and FlavorStratum are what you want

Comment: @JarredKeneally I tried with a Premier version and Pro version and got the same FlavorStratum "standard_stratum"

Comment: Voting to reopen - this is clearly a question about the API in QB and seems valid for SO.

Comment: Can you confirm that was 2 separate company files and 2 separate realms you queried for? Both successfully synced to the cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro & Premier both return standard_stratum

Enterprise returns - bel_stratum

thanks
Jarred

Comment: Shucks!  We need to distinguish between Pro and the others because Pro doesn't have Sales Orders.  I hope Intuit builds this in at some point.  For now, we'll have to have a user tell us via a setting.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I have a better answer for you. 
You can use the existing API [NameValue](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v2/qbd_v2_reference/0600_object_reference/namevalue):
The response DBFlavorNumber will have a number which I listed below and you can determine if it is Pro or Premier

```
<Name>DBFlavorNumber</Name>
```

QB Flavor to SKU mapping
100 = Basic
101 = QuickBooks Pro feature code
102 = QuickBooks Accountant feature code
103 = QuickBooks POS feature code
104 = QuickBooks Premier feature code
105 = QuickBooks Construction SKU feature code
106 = QuickBooks Capri feature code
107 = QuickBooks Non-Profit feature code
108 = Master Builder ICBS Flavor String
109 = QB Enterprise Solutions Accountant feature code
110 = Financial Statement Flavor String
111 = Premier Healthcare Flavor String
112 = Enterprise Healthcare Flavor String
113 = QB Enterprise Contractor Flavor String
114 = Enterprise Non-Profit Flavor String
115 = Estimator Flavor String
116 = Atom Flavor String
117 = Highland Flavor String
118 = Property Management Flavor String
119 = Premier Retail feature code
120 = Premier Professional Flavor String
121 = Premier Mfg & Wholesale
122 = QB Enterprise Professional Flavor String
123 = QB Enterprise Retail Flavor String
124 = QB Enterprise Mfg & Wholesale feature code
125 = QB Premier Convertible Flavor String
126 = Highland Flavor String
127 = QuickBooks Lite Flavor
128 = QB Enterprise Convertible Flavor String
129 = QB Pro for Mac Flavor String
130 = QB New User for Mac Flavor String
131 = QB Premier Vanilla Convertible Flavor String
132 = POS Basic Flavor String
133 = POS Pro Flavor String
134 = POS Pro Multi-Store Flavor String

Comment: So much for creating an enum for these ... Highland is on here twice.